# jest test having issue with accessing global variable initialized from imported modules

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm having issue with accessing initialized db when called from scoket.test.js. socket.test.js invokes handle_wait_for_notificationsForTest defined in socket_util.js. socket.js initializes db with db.initialize. db.getClient in handle_wait_for_notificationsForTest can access initialized db which should be accessible to other modules after initialization. wait_for_notifications defined in socket.js invoked from handle_wait_for_notificationsForTest fails in db.getClient. I can't figure out why its happening when invoked from jest test but not from regular node modules.

```
Call stack:
failure: socket.test.js -> socket_util.js(initialized db) -> socket.js(db.getClient failure because pool not initialized)
success: a.js ->socket_util(initialized db) -> socket.js (db.getClient success. pool initialized )

db.js 

const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pools = {}
exports.initialize = function (name, dbConfig) {
  pools[name] = new Pool(dbConfig)
  pools[name].on('error', function (err, client) {
   console.error('Error in client pool (' + name + ')')
  })
}

exports.getClient = function (name, cb) {
  if (typeof pools[name] === 'undefined') {
    return new Error('DB not initialized.')
  }
  pools[name].connect(cb)
}

exports.getClientAsync = async function (name) {
  if (typeof pools[name] === 'undefined') {
    return Error('DB not initialized.')
  }
  return await pools[name].connect().catch(e => console.error(`Pool.connect(): ${e}`))
}

socket.js 
const _ = require('lodash')
const db = require('./db')
const sio = require('socket.io')
const subscriptionMgr = require('./subscriptionManager')
const util = require('../util')

function wait_for_notifications (io) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const subs = subscriptionMgr.get(2)
    console.log(subs)
    console.log('called wait for notification')
    db.getClient('tps', function (err, client, done) {
     if (handle_notification_error(err, done)) {
       console.log('this is err', err)
         return reject(err)
        }
       …
    })
  })
}

socket_util.js 

const express = require('express')
const db = require('../lib/db')
const app = express()
const subMgr = require('../lib/subscriptionManager')
const socket = rewire('../lib/socket.js')
const server_socket = require('./server_socket')
const client_socket = require('./client_socket')
const wait_for_notifications = socket.__get__('wait_for_notifications')
const dbConfig = {
  port: 5435,
  database: 'tps',
  host: 'localhost',
  user: ''
}
db.initialize('tps', dbConfig)
function handle_wait_for_notificationsForTest (runId, socketId, progress1, progress2, io) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   db.getClient('tps', async function (err, client, done) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
      subMgr.add(runId, socketId)
      wait_for_notifications(io)
    })
  })
}

 

async function calltest () {

  const [io, server] = setServer()
  const client = await getServerIoClient(msgReceived)
  const handled_data = await handle_wait_for_notificationsForTest(2, client.id, 80, 15, io)
  await delay(1000)
  console.log('handled_data', handled_data)
  await closeResources(server, client)
  console.log('end')
}

calltest()

Socket.test.js

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
const path = require('path')
const util = require('./socket_util.js')

test('run wait for notifications test ', async () => {
 const expected_result1 = {
   id: 2,
   progress: 70
    }
    const runId = 2
    const [io, server] = util.setServer()
    const client = await util.getServerIoClient(util.msgReceived)
    console.log('client', client.id)

    const result = await util.handle_wait_for_notificationsForTest(runId, client.id, 70, 100, io)

    console.log('resule from emit progress', result)

    await util.closeResources(server, client)

    expect(result.progress).toEqual(expected_result1.progress)


  })
```